# Spring LdapTemplate authenticate and Heap Inspection attacks

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

I am using the spring-ldap module specifically the LdapTemplate class for authentication with an LDAP Server. (authenticate methods)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html

The issue I have with calling this method is that it uses a String for the password. That exposes these calls to Heap Inspection attacks because the immutable String hangs around in memory for a while until GC'ed after use.

Are there alternate ways to use this module so that we can pass a CharSequence instead that is zero'ed out after use?

Comment: You can store the password in encrypted form using LdapShaPasswordEncoder and on top of it can use any SALT as well for double protection. Spring security supports both of these features.

Comment: Yes, but I need to send the password to ldap without hashing it. Password policies like not using any of past 4-5 passwords or password complexity policies are implemented on the LDAP server. So the ldap server needs to look at the un-hashed password.

Comment: I believe any recommended secure password traversal algo from client to web app server could satisfy your use case. Something like decrypting password at client side only or capturing the password as char or byte array and then transmit to server. You can get more details on owasp recommendations.

Comment: Yes I agree with OWASP recommendations. I am just trying to figure if I am missing something in the spring-ldap module or am using it wrong. Because to use that library I would have to provide a plain text immutable String. I don't see any method overloading that lets me use a byte array.

Comment: To compare the apacheds client api uses char arrays https://directory.apache.org/api/gen-docs/latest/apidocs/org/apache/directory/ldap/client/template/LdapConnectionTemplate.html#authenticate(org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.SearchRequest,%20char[])

Comment: I agree to your part but only thing that i cant deny is that the spring security project owners would also have been thought of such cases and if still they have provided String implementation for password then there should be some idea. While stumbling to there jira list for similar case i came across this. Pls go through it, may be then you feel more comfortable while using String for password. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/170